# How do I create a class in Python that behaves like Django's abstract base class?

Tags: python, django, abstract, metaclass

I'm using an existing Django library and I'm creating a class that I'd like to be abstract.

Let's say the class in question is `BaseFoo`.

Currently, the implementation has a base class `BaseFoo`.

Each time a class extending `BaseFoo` is created, a metaclass adds it to a list of classes. It explicitly doesn't add `BaseFoo` by doing a hard-coded test for the class name:

```
    if name not in ('BaseFoo',):
        class_list.append(new_cls)
```

I'd like to be able to write something like:

```
class MyBaseFoo(BaseFoo):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

And have the metaclass skip all `BaseFoo` objects that are abstract. So I guess I'm wondering how Django does the same thing with models and whether there is an easy, elegant way to do this myself.

I've looked through some of the code Django uses to define models but I could use some pointers. Also if there is an even easier way of doing this without necessarily using `class Meta` I'm open to that too.

Note that I am not particularly thrilled by this solution:

```
class MyBaseFoo(BaseFoo):
    abstract = True

class ActualFoo1(MyBaseFoo):
    abstract = False

class ActualFoo2(MyBaseFoo):
    abstract = False
```

Comment: `name not in ('BaseFoo')` doesn't do what you think it does - it checks if `name` is a substring of `BaseFoo` (so with `name = 'Foo'`, this would be False). To create a singleton tuple, use `('BaseFoo',)` (note the trailing comma) -- but then again, why not `name != 'BaseFoo'`?

Comment: +1 (offsetting) why the downvote? What exactly is wrong with this question?

Comment: Yeah, there was a typo in my code. This is obfuscated code...the original version actually said `name not in ('BaseFoo','OtherBaseFoo')` but I wanted to simplify...oops.

Comment: @bob Yeah, there's no pleasing some people

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to set abstract to False in concrete classes - it's sufficient to have this setting in the abstract classes only:

```
class_list = []
class CollectSubclasses(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        abstract = False
        if attrs.get('abstract', False):
            abstract = True
            del attrs['abstract']
        res = super(CollectSubclasses, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        if not abstract:
            class_list.append(res)
        return res

class BaseFoo(object):
    __metaclass__ = CollectSubclasses
    abstract = True

class Concrete1(BaseFoo):
    pass

class Abstract(BaseFoo):
    abstract = True

class Concrete2(Abstract):
    pass

print class_list
```

An alternative might be class decorators in Python 2.6, however, you would need to remove the class from the class_list in the @abstract decorator, since it has already been created when the decorator is called (and hence the metaclass was already invoked).

Comment: +1 Nice solution.  Does `abstract=False` actually result in it being abstract?

Comment: @kevpie: It didn't originally, but does now.